# switch case for parsing options

Tags: c, pointers

I am writing a simple program which takes the arguments form the user and process them.
I have the arguments in the argv which is two dimensional array. But when i ran the program, i get the garbage value and the segmentation fault error. I have tried with using argc as terminating condition and it works. But i want to  do it using the pointer only.
What am doing wrong with pointer here.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while (++(*argv))
    {
        if ( **argv == '-' )
        {
            switch (*argv[1])  
            {
                default:
                    printf("Unknown option -%c\n\n", (*argv)[1]);
                    break;
                case 'h':
                    printf("\n option h is found");
                    break;
                case 'v':
                    printf("option V is found");
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    printf("\n option d is found");
                    break;
            }
        }
        printf("\n outside while : %s", *argv);
    }
}
```

program run as:

```
./a.out -h -v -d
```

Thank you

Comment: Also, why are you not using `getopt()` for parsing the command line?

Comment: @H2CO3: Perhaps it is an exercise -- a way to illustrate how option parsing can get difficult. Then in the next lesson, the big reveal: getopt can do it for you! It sounds like something I'd do just to listen to students grumble about having to go through what may seem to have been a waste of time after discovering getopt.

Comment: Even after making the corrections suggested in the selected answer, try running your program with this command line "./a.out - "  You should handle the null character in your switch statement...

Comment: Well, one possible reason is that `getopt` is not a standard function.

Comment: @AndreyT: `getopt` is a standard posix function. It's not a standard C function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- If you want to iterate through program arguments looking for the terminating null pointer, your outer cycle should be

  ```
  while (*++argv)
  ```

  not the

  ```
  while (++*argv) // <- incorrect!
  ```

  that you have in your code.
- Your `switch` expression is written incorrectly. While your intent is clear, your implementation ignores operator precedence.

  This

  ```
  switch (*argv[1])  { // <- incorrect!
  ```

  should actually be

  ```
  switch ((*argv)[1])  {
  ```
- The previous `if`

  ```
  if (**argv == '-')
  ```

  is fine, but since it is equivalent to

  ```
  if ((*argv)[0] == '-') // <- better
  ```

  maybe you should rewrite it that way as well, just for consistency with `switch`.

Comment: Thanks @AndreyT. while(*++argv) and switch((*argv)[1]) works file as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Your ultimate problem is operator precedence. Don't try to be clever when it's unnecessary. The `*` operator does not work as you think it does. I've rewritten your code using `[0]` instead, and now it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while ((++argv)[0])
    {
            if (argv[0][0] == '-' )
            {
                    switch (argv[0][1])  {

                            default:
                                    printf("Unknown option -%c\n\n", argv[0][1]);
                                    break;
                            case 'h':
                                    printf("\n option h is found");
                                    break;
                            case 'v':
                                    printf("option V is found");
                                    break;
                            case 'd':
                                    printf("\n option d is found");
                                    break;
                    }
            }

            printf("\n outside while : %s", argv[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`argv` is an array of strings. `argv[0]` is the program name which in your case is `a.out`. Your options start from `argv[1]`. So you need to iterate `argv` from 1 to `argc-1` to get the options.

Also see here: [Parsing Program Arguments](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html)

Comment: The OP apparently intended to make the outer cycle `while (*++argv))`. It already skips over the "program name" argument. But it is implemented with an error.